# MySQL not showing my database

Tags: mysql, schema

Trying to figure out how to view the tables/schema of a `MySQL` database, but after logging into the db with the root account I am not seeing any option to view the schema or tables of my DB. This is what I see:

[mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcJiU.png)

I am still able to run queries against the db successfully but I need to be able to look at the table structure. Any ideas?

Comment: try running `show databases;` in the `query editor`.

Answer (score 0):

If the panel is not visible, click View, Panels, and then Show Sidebar

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-sql-editor-navigator.html